# Web Services Eclipse

Tags: web-services, eclipse-plugin

When I want to create a new project from File > New Project > Select Web Application from the Java Web category or EJB Module
from the Java EE category; I do not have the Web Application choice.
How can I fix it?

[I followed this steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLsmv.jpg)

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? Which instructions are you following?

Comment: I have oxygen.2 and I add the steps that I followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i might think what you are missing. First you will need to download an additional software. First go to Help -> Install New Software -> Work with : http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/  then click Add -> WEB,XML,Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development and select from there : Axis2 tools , CFX Web Services, Java EE Development Tools,Java EE Developer Tools,Java Web Developer Tools,Web Developer Tools,XML Editors and tools and other that you might think will help you. Hit the next button and proceed the installation. Restart eclipse.The go to File -> New -> Other -> Dynamic web project.